# Number of Polynomials and continuous functions on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, cardinals

The question is what is the cardinalyty of

> $1)$ $\mathcal P=$The set of all polynomials with real co-efficient and
>
> $2)$ $\mathcal R=$The set of all  real valued continuous functions

Now a polynomial's standard form is $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+....+a_0$ where $x$ is the variable and $a_i\in \mathbb R \forall i.$

So for a fixed $n$, the cardinality of such polynomials is $|\mathbb R^n|=c.$

The set of all polynomials is bijective with the set $\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb R^n.$ Hence the cardinality is $$\left|\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb R^n\right|\\=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1.c\\=|\mathbb N|\cdot c\\=c$$

Am I correct here.

But every continuous function can be wrtten as the limit of a sequence of polynomials. So, $\mathcal R=\bar {\mathcal P}$ So we can say that $$\mathcal R\supset \mathcal P\\\implies |\mathcal R|\ge |\mathcal P|=c.$$

Now what do I do to find an equality$?$

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct that the set $\mathcal{P}$ of polynomials with real coefficients has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}.$

The set $\mathcal{R}$ of all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ also has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}.$  One easy way to see this is to observe that any continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is uniquely determined by its values on the set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers (this is true since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}).$  It follows that the function $i\colon\mathcal{R}\to {}^\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{R}$ defined by setting $i(f)$ equal to the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ is an injection. $({}^\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{R}$ here denotes the set of all functions from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}.)$

But $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so the cardinality of ${}^\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{R}$ equals the cardinality of ${}^\mathbb{N}\mathbb{R},$ which is $\mathfrak{c}.$  It follows that the cardinality of $\mathcal{R}$ is less than or equal to $\mathfrak{c}.$

Now $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathcal{R},$ and you already showed that the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}$ is $\mathfrak{c},$ so we have that the cardinality of $\mathcal{R}$ is greater than or equal to $\mathfrak{c}.$

We conclude that the cardinality of $\mathcal{R}$ is equal to $\mathfrak{c}.$

Comment: Another way to see that the cardinal of the set of continuous real functions is  not greater than $c$ is to observe that the set of countable real sequences has cardinal $c.$  Bijectively identify the set of sequences of polynomials that converge point-wise to continuous functions with   a subset of the set of real sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $A$ of polynomials with rational coefficients. This is a countable set.

A continuous function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is the uniform limit of polynomials with rational coefficients by the [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). Thus, such a function can be identified with a sequence $\{p_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset A$ such that $\|p_n-f\|_\infty<1/n$. Hence, $f$ can be identified with a subset of $A$. In order to show that the identification is injective we have to show that we can recover $f$ uniquely from a subset $\{q_i:i\in \mathbb N\}$ of $A$, where $q_i$ is in $1-1$ correspondence with some sequence $p_n$ converging to $f$ as above. For each $n_0\in \mathbb N$, if $i_0\in \mathbb N$ is sufficiently large, we have $\{1,\dots,i_0\} \supset  \{1,\dots,n_0\}$, and therefore $\|p_n-f\|_{\infty} <1/n_0$ for all $n\geq n_0$ and $\|q_i-f\|_{\infty}<1/n_0$ for all $i> i_0$. Thus $q_i$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Thus $f$ can be identified with an element of $\mathcal P(A)$, and this shows that $C([0,1])$ has cardinality at most $c=2^{\mathbb N}$.

It is not hard to generalize this to continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, e.g. you can use a sequence $p_n$ of polynomials such that $p_n$ approximates $f$ very well in the interval $[-n,n]$.

Comment: Suggested clarification: the correspondence (function) $\mapsto$ (some *concrete* sequence converging to function) is injective.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: How does that help? What you really need is the opposite, as you only get some sequences anyway. (And then finish via Cantor-Bernstein.)

Answer (score 1):

Establish the following facts:

1. $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal P$ have at least the cardinality of continuum. (Consider the constants)
2. Any continuous function on $\mathbb R$ is completely determined by its values on the rational numbers, and hence can have at most the cardinality of $\mathfrak c$.
3. $\mathcal P \subseteq \mathcal R$